# mathmode is causing compilation errors, \[ is not well recognized

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

I have this piece of latex code:

```
\documentclass{paper}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\[
W_0=W\\
W_i= ext(W_{i-1}),\ i < \beta
\]
\end{document}
```

When compiling I get these problems:

- line 8: Environment equation* undefined. [
- line 9: Missing $
  inserted. W_
- line 11: \begin{document} ended by \end{equation*}. ]
- line 11: Missing $ inserted. ]

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
Complete log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.4)  23 MAR 2020 23:14
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paper/paper.cls
Document Class: paper 2008/05/30 1.0l LaTeX document class (wm).
\hours=\count80
\minutes=\count81
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\beforetitlespace=\skip41
\c@part=\count82
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\exampleindent=\skip42
\c@figure=\count88
\c@table=\count89
\abovecaptionskip=\skip43
\belowcaptionskip=\skip44
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip45

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 223.
\uproot@=\count91
\leftroot@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 385.
\classnum@=\count93
\DOTSCASE@=\count94
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 482.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 485.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 606.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box27
\strutbox@=\box28
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 729.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 730.
\macc@depth=\count95
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count96
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count97
\dspbrk@lvl=\count98
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count99
\column@=\count100
\maxfields@=\count101
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip46
\multlinetaggap=\skip47
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2836.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2837.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks19
\inpenc@posthook=\toks20
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (./document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.


! LaTeX Error: Environment equation* undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8     \[

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9     W_
       0=W\\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{equation*}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11    \]

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11    \]

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+cmss on input line 12.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd
File: t1cmss.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1223 strings out of 494553
 13406 string characters out of 6177378
 68854 words of memory out of 5000000
 4947 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6391 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,7n,21p,231b,222s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 </home/younes/.texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknap
pen/ec/ecrm1000.600pk> </home/younes/.texlive2019/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jkn
appen/ec/ecrm0900.600pk></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmmi7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb>
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 40047 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 38 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 27 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

**List of files (\listfiles) **

```
 *File List*
   paper.cls    2008/05/30 1.0l LaTeX document class (wm).
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
inputenc.sty    2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
  t1cmss.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

Thanks in advacne,

Comment: No problem here. Can you also post the `.log`?

Comment: The error message you quote complaines about `equation* ` being undefined. However, your code does not contain `equation* `. Are you certain the above quoted error messages resukt from this exact code?

Comment: @leandriis Yes I confirm

Comment: @Werner log added to question

Comment: You ***cannot*** have ``\\`` inside `\[...\]`.

Comment: @Werner I don't think so, I installed it not long ago,

Comment: @egreg I tried without it but same problem

Comment: @youneszeboudj Please, add `\listfiles` at the top of the document and recompile; the file list will be printed towards the end of the log file. Please report it.

Comment: I just retried by removing `\usepackage{amsmath}` and it worked fine! I think `amsmath` is redefining \[ somehow ! probably `amsmath` is outadated, is there an easy way to find this out ?

Comment: @egreg list of files added

Comment: It looks like current `amsmath` is a beta version !

Comment: No your file list is correct for texlive 2018. texlive 2019 and texlive 2020 have slightly newer versions of some of that list but all three give the same output, no error and the `\\ ` is ignored.

Comment: as your banner is debian texlive 2019 you can probably update it using the standard debian apt package system

Comment: @leandriis -- `amsmath` (re)defines `\[` and `\]` in terms pf `equation*`.  (But it's a mystery to me why this file should fail.)

Comment: I'll do more research tommorow on how to handle this, meanwhile I would be interested of you have any suggestions?

Comment: @David Carlisle I'll try to update it tommorow

Comment: Updating texlive fixed the issue, thanks all for your help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could not be replicated. An update finally resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after updating texlive `sudo apt-get install texlive`